# Use UiTableViewCell subclass as Monotouch.Dialog Element

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to figure out how to:
1. use IB, in Xcode 4+ to visually create a custom subclass of UITableViewCell to use in MT.

2. How to use that custom class as an element in MT.Dialog.

I have searched extensively and haven't found any example or been able to solve it.
Here is the process I have been trying:

1. Step 1 seems easy enough now that I have found a good tutorial: http://www.arcticmill.com/2012/05/uitableview-with-custom-uitableviewcell.html
2. Step 2 seems to be where I am stuck. Once I have the new class, with a few labels dropped onto it in this case:

   ```
   public partial class CustomListCell : UITableViewCell {
     public CustomListCell () :base(UITableViewCellStyle.Default,"CellID") { 
     }

     public void UpDateData(string lbl1, string lbl2, string lbl3) {
       this.lblLabel1.Text = lbl1;
       this.lblLabel2.Text = lbl2;
       this.lblLabel3.Text = lbl3;
     }
   }
   ```

I cannot figure out how to turn it into something I can use in MT.Dialog. I have tried :

```
public partial class CustomListCell :Element
```

but the label controls don't seem to every be created.No matter where I put a call to UpdateData they are all null, hence a null reference exception, even if the constructor has executed just fine.  I've also tried making it an OwnerDrawnElement, but ran into a couple of problems with that.

Is this possible? Is there a recommended pattern?

Answer (score 0):

I think the sample you are looking for is the OwnerDrawnCell: https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog/blob/master/MonoTouch.Dialog/Elements/OwnerDrawnElement.cs

See how it overrides the GetCell() method to provide a custom cell:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tv)
{
  OwnerDrawnCell cell = tv.DequeueReusableCell(this.CellReuseIdentifier) as OwnerDrawnCell;

  if (cell == null)
  {
    cell = new OwnerDrawnCell(this, this.Style, this.CellReuseIdentifier);
  }
  else
  {
    cell.Element = this;
  }

  cell.Update();
  return cell;
}
```

You just need to do the same thing - except you need to replace OwnerDrawnCell with the XIB-loaded cell.

---

I've also done a blog post on how I load cells from XIBs using the new iOS6 variant of the DequeueReusableCell API - see http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/01/uitableviewcell-using-xib-editor.html